# How can I make firebase rules that allow auth users to read all documents but only create their own user document not giving themselves admin rights?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am struggling with the firebase security rules, I can get parts of it to work, but when I try to connect it all together I am having issues.
I would like to have my rules do the following:

1. Allow read to all documents if authenticated
2. Allow create or update user document by authenticated only at document /databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)  but not add admin to the roles array 
   !("admin" in getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles)
3. Allow only getRole(“admin”) == true to create, edit, or delete any user document and any other document

```
function getRole(role) {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles.hasAny([role]);
  }
```

Here is what I have that does not include the users being able to create their own user account.  It works to allow only admin to write any document.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  function getRole(role) {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles.hasAny([role]);
  }
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if getRole('admin') == true;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what I tried to add to allow users to create their user document.  It seems to be not cascading to the next rule, it tries the getRole in the `match /{document=**}` path and finds that the user is not an admin so it fails.  I have tried reordering and placing the /users/ path above and it goes thru that path fine then does the same thing and fails on the getRole in the `/{document=**}` path again.  I also tried specifying the document names rather than using the wildcard and that seems to not allow any get or write.  Can you please point me in the right direction?

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  function getRole(role) {
    return exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)) && get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles.hasAny([role]);
  }
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if getRole('admin') == true;
    }
    match /users/{userId}{
      allow read: if  request.auth.uid != null;
      allow create: if getRole('admin') == true ||  request.auth.uid == userId  &&
            !(getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles.hasAny(["admin"]));
      allow update: if getRole('admin') == true ||  request.auth.uid == userId  && exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)) == true && !(getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles.hasAny(["admin"]));
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I can't allow admin to dynamically create collections that are not defined in the security rules unless I use the `match /{document=**}` which applies those rules to every path and is not the desired result.  I was able to get the rules setup to accomplish the other parts pretty easily as follows:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
   function getRole(role) {
    return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles.hasAny([role]);
  }
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow create: if request.auth.uid == userId && request.resource.data.roles.hasAny(["admin"]) == false;
    }
    match /collectionName/{collectionNameId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null && getRole('admin') == true;
    }
  }
}
```